# SEDE bug: Anonymous users asked to solve captcha, but captcha not shown

Tags: bug, data-explorer

To reproduce:

- Visit a SEDE query without being logged in
- Click "Run Query"
- "I'm not a robot" challenge is displayed and the message "Anonymous users must solve a captcha. Please complete the captcha and submit again." at the bottom highlighted in red

No captcha is ever displayed (super tough to solve!).

Clicking "I'm not a robot" can be done, but has no positive effect.

Comment: I can't repro. You do know you have to click "Run Query" again after you clicked "I'm not a robot", right?

Comment: @rene It’s still a bug, because as a user I’m looking for the captcha to solve and left scratching my head - a red message like that indicates an error by the user, but no error occurred. The correct message to display is no message at all - the challenge is obvious and needs no message. Only if there was an *error* by the user should a message be displayed in red like that.

Comment: let's agree on that the UX is subpar.